# AWS Lambda to interact with CodeCommit in C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codecommit

I have written a simple AWS Lambda in python that is triggered by a CodeCommit event. It receives information about the event and does some processing on committed objects before writing them out to an S3 bucket. I need to add substantial new functionality so I would like to re-write what I have in C#. However, I can't find a nuget package like Amazon.Lambda.CodeCommitEvents. I think I know the answer but I want to confirm, the AWSSDK for C# doesn't support CodeCommit events for lambdas, does it? Or am I missing something?

If there is an alternate approach, I'm open to any suggestions. Basically, I need to executing some custom compiling on my CodeCommit events. Alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

What specific Event types are you looking for? There are a number of CodeCommit event classes in the [Amazon.CodeCommit.Model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/CodeCommit/NCodeCommitModel.html) namespace. You can find it in the [AWSSDK.CodeCommit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.CodeCommit/) nuget package.

Comment: There should be an event that would match the contents that a Lambda triggered by a CodeCommit event should get. I found an AmazonCodeCommitRequest, but that is an empty base class. I would expect there to be an event more similar to the APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest that exists when you create the example project.